# IE11 Script1002 Syntax Error. WebpackJsonP is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I am using Typescript & WebPack 3 and when testing in development mode in IE11 I run into issues. The errors I get are:

- Script1002: Syntax Error. vendor.bundle.js
- Script5009: webpackJsonp is undefined. main.bundle.js

`vendor.bundle.js` is loaded before my `main.bundle.js` so that is not the issue. If I look at line in `vendor.bundle.js` that has the error is

```
class Features {
  // ...
}
```

I am assuming then that the error is because class is an ES6 feature and IE11 doesnt support it. This is a dependency in the `node_modules` directory and it's a `js` file and written in ES6.

My question then is, assuming this is all correct (I am not 100% sure hence the backstory) then how do I get webpack to convert this to ES5? I set the target in my `tsconfig.json` to ES5 for my Typescript but that is obviously not helping here.

Interestingly, if I check the source code of the offending `node_module` the src is ES6 but the dist files are ES5. Is there anyway to ensure WebPack bundles the dist files or is it better to include via normal `import` mechanism and let WebPack transpile the code?

module.exports = function (env) {
    var nodeEnv = env && env.prod ? "production" : "development";
    var isProd = nodeEnv === "production";

```
var plugins = [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: true,
        template: "../index.html",
        filename: "index.html" //relative to root of the application
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "vendor",
        minChunks: Infinity,
        filename: "vendor.bundle.js"
    }),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
        NODE_ENV: nodeEnv,
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: "app.bundle.css",
        disable: !isProd
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        "_": "lodash",
        "window.moment": "moment",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\.\/locale$/)
];

if (isProd) {
    plugins.push(new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: '[file].js.map',
        append: false,
        exclude: ['vendor.bundle.js']
    }));

    plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        parallel: true,
        mangle: true,
        compress: {
            warnings: false,
            screw_ie8: true,
            conditionals: true,
            unused: true,
            comparisons: true,
            sequences: true,
            dead_code: true,
            evaluate: true,
            if_return: true,
            join_vars: true,
        },
        output: {
            comments: false,
        },
    }));
}
else {
    plugins.push(new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: '[file].js.map',
        exclude: ['vendor.bundle.js']
    }));

    plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    plugins.push(new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin());
}

return {
    watch: !isProd,
    context: sourcePath,
    entry: {
        main: sourcePath + "/bootstrap.ts",
        vendor: ["@uirouter/angularjs/release/stateEvents.js"].concat(Object.keys(package.dependencies))
    },
    output: {
        path: destPath,
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "html-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(s*)css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: { minimize: isProd, sourceMap: true }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "postcss-loader",
                            options: { sourceMap: true }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: { sourceMap: true }
                        }
                    ],
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["awesome-typescript-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".ts"],
        modules: [
            "node_modules"
        ]
    },

    plugins: plugins,

    performance: isProd && {
        maxAssetSize: 100,
        maxEntrypointSize: 300,
        hints: "warning",
    },

    stats: {
        colors: {
            green: "\u001b[32m",
        }
    },

    devServer: {
        //contentBase: "./src",
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: 3000,
        compress: isProd,
        inline: !isProd,
        hot: !isProd,
        stats: {
            assets: true,
            children: false,
            chunks: false,
            hash: false,
            modules: false,
            publicPath: false,
            timings: true,
            version: false,
            warnings: true,
            colors: {
                green: "\u001b[32m",
            }
        },
    }
};
```

};

Comment: so, did you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

> is it better to include via normal import mechanism and let WebPack transpile the code?

Correct.

[Normally typescript wouldn't transpile any of your node modules, you would import the build files of those modules which are normally transpiled ES5.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

If that isn't working for some reason then you may need to pass your compiled typescript through babel with webpack to get a final ES5 bundle.

[See here an example of cascading through ts then babel loaders to achieve the desired output.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/blob/master/react-flux-babel-karma/webpack.config.js#L40)

This should not normally be necessary though as you should be using the ES5 version of your imports.

Comment: Thank you for answering, the issue however isn't that my Typescript code isnt being transpiled correctly, it is that an imported `node_module` is using ES6 features and IE11 cannot understand them

Comment: Yes I understand that. The issue is that your node module is using ES6 features when it should not be, you should be consuming the ES5 built code from the module.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check and confirm your webpack-dev-server version.
I was also facing similar issue with latest version of webpack-dev-server and transpiled/bundled code was working on IE11 [Prod] but not on webpack-dev-server.

After downgrading to version 2.7.1, it worked.

Comment: Thank you - I just tried this but it didn't work though ;/